# Spring boot :Unable to load view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am unable to load home.html with following configuration. Controller always redirects to src/main/resources/templates/error.html. What can be the issue?
I have also included thymleaf dependency in my pom, going by one such suggestion.
Config class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.sg.repository.")
public class SgmembersApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(SgmembersApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf) {
        return hemf.getSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

**src/main/resources/templates/home.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>  
    <title>Members</title> 
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
   <label> This is home page</label>    
  </body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {


     @RequestMapping("/")
     public String getHomePage() {
         return "home";
     }

     @RequestMapping("/error")
     public String getErrorPage() {
         return "error";
     }
```

**application.properties**

```
    # Database
spring.datasource.driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sg
spring.datasource.username: 
spring.datasource.password: 

# Hibernate
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext

#tomcat bind address
server.port=8181
```

Relevant console trace :

```
2015-12-03 17:52:52.744  INFO 16720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-12-03 17:52:52.747  INFO 16720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'metricFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-03 17:52:52.747  INFO 16720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-03 17:52:52.747  INFO 16720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-03 17:52:52.747  INFO 16720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-03 17:52:52.747  INFO 16720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-03 17:52:52.747  INFO 16720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-03 17:52:52.747  INFO 16720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-03 17:52:53.181  INFO 16720 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-12-03 17:52:53.194  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [


2015-12-03 17:52:54.041  INFO 16720 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-12-03 17:52:54.042  INFO 16720 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-12-03 17:52:54.067  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-12-03 17:52:54.067  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-12-03 17:52:54.108  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-12-03 17:52:54.399  INFO 16720 --- [           main] roperties$SimpleAuthenticationProperties : 


2015-12-03 17:52:55.011  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
2015-12-03 17:52:55.011  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-12-03 17:52:55.012  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2015-12-03 17:52:55.012  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-12-03 17:52:55.012  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-12-03 17:52:55.013  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-12-03 17:52:55.014  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-12-03 17:52:55.015  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-12-03 17:52:55.015  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2015-12-03 17:52:55.016  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-12-03 17:52:55.016  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2015-12-03 17:52:55.016  INFO 16720 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewed your code. Change Your component scan to scan for every relevant package, or just all of the content, e.g. `@ComponentScan("com.sg.")`

Your mappings will then get set correctly:

```
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sg.members.controller.MainController.getHomePage()
```

Some other hints: Thymeleaf expects any HTML-Tag to be closed again. Your home.html will throw a few errors, but it's quite easy to fix by just closing the tags. (e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>`. Mind the "/" at the end.)

Same goes for input, img and every other field.

Comment: Can you show us your error handling configuration and any thymeleaf resolvers you might have?

Comment: I haven't used any resolvers. Just a thymleaf dependency entry in the pom.

Comment: And your error handlers? What exactly redirects to /error?

Comment: when i try to access root : localhost:8181, it instead redirects to localhost:8181/error

Comment: You must have some kind of configuration that leads redirects to that error mapping, otherwise it's kind of useless. You wouldn't call /error manually I assume.

Comment: except application.properties I don't have any other config. correection : It doesn't redirect, but localhost:8181 displays content of error.html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96888/discussion-between-lukehey-and-forkmohit).